# Page number and header problem in APA style

Tags: header-footer, apa-style

Problem1: I am unable to get page numbers in the pdf output

Problem2: How do I prevent anything from being written on the header or if that is not possible how to display correctly something on the header without overspilling the text? Upon using the command

```
\rightheader{Odd-Numbered Page Header}
    \leftheader{Even-Numbered Page Header}
```

I am getting Odd-Numbered Page Header displayed in the header of every page of the pdf.
Please help

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{apacite}
%\usepackage{biblatex-apa}
%these next packages extend the apa class to allow for including statistical and graphic commands
\usepackage{url}   %this allows us to cite URLs in the text
\usepackage{graphicx}  %allows for graphic to float when doing jou or doc style
\usepackage{amssymb}  %use formatting tools  for math symbols
% type setting of functions, packages, and R follows a particular style
\let\proglang=\textsf
\newcommand{\R}{\proglang{R}}
\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{{\normalfont\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1}}
\newcommand{\Rfunction}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fun}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Robject}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
%
%
%Here is where we start the important APA stuff

\title{How to write in APA style}
\author{Latex writer}
\affiliation{Department of Psychology \\ Northwestern University}
%taken from AP's user notes
% John Vokey uses something like this

\ifapamodeman{%

\note{\begin{flushleft}

  William Revelle\\

    Department of Psychology\\

  Northwestern University\\

 Evanston, Illinois\\

    60201\\

    e-mail: revelle@northwestern.edu\\



   \end{flushleft}}}

{%else, i.e., in jou and doc mode

%\note{Draft of \today}
}

\abstract{Template to write in APA format
}
\rightheader{Odd-Numbered Page Header}
\leftheader{Even-Numbered Page Header}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Advantage}

 The Authors etc, 

\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you MWE:

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa}
%\usepackage{amsfonts} % Redundant if you load the amssymb package
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} % use formatting tools  for math symbols
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{apacite}
%\usepackage{biblatex-apa}
%these next packages extend the apa class to allow for including statistical and graphic commands
\usepackage{mwe} % Enables to create MWEs easily and loads lipsum and blindtext packages to create dummy texts
\usepackage{url}   %this allows us to cite URLs in the text
\usepackage{graphicx}  %allows for graphic to float when doing jou or doc style
%\usepackage{amssymb}  %use formatting tools  for math symbols
% type setting of functions, packages, and R follows a particular style
\let\proglang=\textsf
\newcommand{\R}{\proglang{R}}
\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{{\normalfont\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1}}
\newcommand{\Rfunction}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fun}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Robject}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
%
%
%Here is where we start the important APA stuff

\title{How to write in APA style}
\author{Latex writer}
\affiliation{Department of Psychology \\ Northwestern University}
%taken from AP's user notes
% John Vokey uses something like this

\ifapamodeman{%

\note{\begin{flushleft}

  William Revelle\\

    Department of Psychology\\

  Northwestern University\\

 Evanston, Illinois\\

    60201\\

    e-mail: revelle@northwestern.edu\\
   \end{flushleft}}}

{%else, i.e., in jou and doc mode

%\note{Draft of \today}
}

\abstract{Template to write in APA format
}
\rightheader{Odd-Numbered Page Header}
\leftheader{Even-Numbered Page Header}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Advantage}

 The Authors etc, 

\blinddocument % Creates a short document structure (from the blindtext package loaded by mwe)

%\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

I commented the line of the bibliography since isn't necessary for this example. Also I used the line where you loaded the `amssymb` for second time to place the `mwe` package that is helpful for examples here.

I get a pdf with page numbers above in the right side of the header, so I don't see your problem 1.

Regarding to problem 2, I don't know this class you use, but usually with standard classes you can have 4 types of layouts that you control from `\pagestyle{}` command and they are:

1. plain: is the default in some cases and only adds the page number in the footer,
2. empty: doesn't show anything in headers and footers,  such as in title pages,
3. headings: show the default headings included with the class, and
4. myheadings: is in fact a general and abstract name for a custom layout you can create using packages such as `fancyhdr` or `titlesec`.

So if you want to avoid the headers in your documents, instead of the two lines in your code above `\begin{document}` you can use the page style `plain` in this way:

```
.
.
.
%\rightheader{Odd-Numbered Page Header}
%\leftheader{Even-Numbered Page Header}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
.
.
.
```

In this way you'll get only the numbers in the middle of the footers and without headers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Problem2 is solved from your technique. But for Problem1 - I can see page numbers from 2 onwards. But there is no page number "1", page numbering starts from second page onwards as "2","3" etc at the footer.

Comment: Well that's perfectly normal since the editorial tradition states that the initial page or where a new chapter open will not be numbered. When Donald Knuth created `TeX` he took into account these conventions. I'm pretty sure you can change that, but it's not something that bothers me and I have never given the task to find out.